# How to Convert a Number to Roman Numerals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, convention

i don't How to Convert a Number to Roman Numerals Using mathematical equation.
if M=1000,D=500,C=100,L=50,X=10,V=5,I=1 then how convert any decimal number to
Roman Numerals?

such as if 1952 then its look like MCMLII

if any one know method please help me to learn this method .
am just waiting for your help :)

Comment: program: http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/07/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing this site, which also has a converter.

http://www.mathsisfun.com/roman-numerals.html

If you were looking for an algorithm, see:

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/01/project-euler-89-converting-to-and-from.html

This question was also answered on StackOverflow using C-Code: see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986521/how-to-convert-integer-value-to-roman-numeral-string (see ValueConverter answer for an efficient approach)

Enjoy!

-A

Comment: Good ole' Roman Numerals! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The second link (`blog.functionalfun.net`) has the most efficient and simplest algorithm for both encoding and decoding, I’d say.